# dd-trace errors out with node.js jest test run

Tags: jestjs, trace, datadog

i have a node.js application and using jest for unit testing..  i use the following to use dd-trace lib..
`const tracer = require('dd-trace').init();`

app works good, however when i try to run unit test via jest, just this init line alone cause the following error:

> jest --coverage --verbose

FAIL  plugins/**tests**/Apputils.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'root' of 'path.parse(...)' as it is undefined.

  3 | const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
> 4 | const tracer = require('dd-trace').init();
    |                ^
  5 | var StatsD = require('hot-shots');
  6 | var dogstatsd = new StatsD();

  at findUp (node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/pkg.js:25:11)
  at findPkg (node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/pkg.js:14:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/pkg.js:37:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/config.js:7:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/proxy.js:6:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/index.js:4:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/dd-trace/index.js:3:18)
```

Any idea to get this working?

if I remove this line, all works well..
`const tracer = require('dd-trace').init();`

Comment: This is more of a bug report than a question. Can you open an issue in https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-js/issues? Then we'll take a look as soon as possible. Please make sure to include all the requested information like OS information and Node version.